# WPF: Право на ввод только ЗАГЛАВНЫХ,РУССКИХ букв в textBox(числа нельзя вводить)

Tags: c#, wpf

А также чтобы пользователь не мог стирать буквы
Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Не надо мучить пользователей запретами. Вы же не хотите, чтобы Вас проклинали? Просто преобразуйте введённую строку в верхний регистр. Можно сразу по ходу ввода, можно потом целиком.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void TextBox_OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    char inp = e.Text[0];
    if (inp < 'А' || inp > 'Я')
        e.Handled = true;
}

private void TextBox_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Space)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Учтите, что в этом варианте возможен хак при помощи `Ctrl + V`

Comment: А зачем `base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);`? Вы ж не перекрываете виртуальный метод?

Comment: @VladD +, уже на автомате их пишу) Действительно не нужен этот вызов.

Comment: Вы можете ещё и убрать `Ctrl + V`, если допишете `DataObject.Pasting="OnPasting" ContextMenu="{x:Null}"` в XAML и `void OnPasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e) => e.CancelCommand();` в code-behind.

Comment: А почему вы анализируете только `e.Text[0]`? А если там больше символов?

Comment: @VladD не больше. С каждым нажатием туда приходит ровно один символ, причем BackSpace и Space там не учитываются, поэтому для них использовал другой обработчик.

Comment: Хм. А если юзер вставляет текст при помощи `Ctrl + V` или там UI Automation?

Comment: @VladD очевидно, я поэтому и уточнил в ответе, что возможен хак с `Ctrl + V`

Comment: @VladD кстати, в вашем решении возможна вставка через контекстное меню. Вероятно, `ContextMenu="{x:Null}"` надо писать уже _внутри_ `<TextBox>`

Comment: Ну да, я именно это и имел в виду. И `DataObject.Pasting="OnPasting"` тоже.